# Android Library styleable attr, does not work in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Bindings Library according to the documentation, however when cou use the control in Xamarin does not work, says that the error in the project line: https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/orangegangsters/github/swipyrefreshlayout/library/SwipyRefreshLayout.java#L294

Looking the speech logs:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.R$styleable"

Some say you have to put "publish Default true" to compile the library, but in my case it did not work, if you have any suggestions of what can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Clone the `SwipyRefreshLayout` repo

2) Build the project in **Android Studio** to produce the debug & release `aar`'s

3) Use the release `aar` in your `Xamarin.Android` binding project

```
./lib/build/outputs/aar/lib-release.aar
```

5) Add the Binding project as a reference to your `Xamarin.Android` app.

4) Add the Swipy Java Test app resources to your C# app

*Note: This is just a shortcut to skip having to manually recreate them for the test app.*

5) Example C# Swipy code:

```
[Activity(Label = "Swipy", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    string[] items;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button buttonTop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_top);
        buttonTop.Click += onClick;
        Button buttonBottom = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_bottom);
        buttonBottom.Click += onClick;
        Button buttonRefresh = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_refresh);
        buttonRefresh.Click += onClick;
        Button buttonBoth = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_both);
        buttonBoth.Click += onClick;

        items = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", };
        var ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

        ListView listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
        listview.Adapter = ListAdapter;

        SwipyRefreshLayout swipyrefreshlayout = FindViewById<SwipyRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipyrefreshlayout);
        swipyrefreshlayout.Refresh += async (object sender, SwipyRefreshLayout.RefreshEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Log.Debug("MainActivity", "Refresh triggered at " + (e.Direction == SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.Top ? "top" : "bottom"));
            swipyrefreshlayout.Refreshing = true;
            await Task.Delay(2000); // simulate some data refresh
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                swipyrefreshlayout.Refreshing = false;
            });
        };
    }

    async void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwipyRefreshLayout swipyrefreshlayout = FindViewById<SwipyRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipyrefreshlayout);

        var v = (View)sender;
        switch (v.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.button_top:
                swipyrefreshlayout.Direction = SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.Top;
                break;
            case Resource.Id.button_bottom:
                swipyrefreshlayout.Direction = SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.Bottom;
                break;
            case Resource.Id.button_both:
                swipyrefreshlayout.Direction = SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.Both;
                break;
            case Resource.Id.button_refresh:
                swipyrefreshlayout.Refreshing = true;
                await Task.Delay(2000); // simulate some data refresh
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    swipyrefreshlayout.Refreshing = false;
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the resources from the library you are binding are not being included correctly for some reason.

As a temporary workaround you can take the attribute XML and include directly in your project, which should resolve the issue.

In either case, you should raise an issue on [Xamarin Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com), with the reproducible steps to get this fixed in a future release.

Comment: No bug, he is just not using a correctly build `aar` that has the resources in it.

Comment: I did not try this alternative, but can be a good option when you have the file .aar